# amazon aws bucket policy to let my ec2 server get files programmatically

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

It seems like I should be able to make a rule to allow access from my ec2's elastic ip. Here is the code I have:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Id": "S3PolicyId1",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "IPAllow",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": "s3:GetObject",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::big18v1/*",
        "Condition": {
            "IpAddress": {
                "aws:SourceIp": "12.123.12.123"
            }
        }
    }
]
```

}

but.. it doesn't work.  I get 'access denied'

any thoughts?  I've read over and over about creating iam roles and things like that, but I don't really want to manipulate the bucket files... I just want to use the bucket like a server and get image files from it.

Am I thinking about this right?  How should I let only my ec2 instance have access to my s3 bucket?

Answer (score 0):

You should create an IAM role with access to the bucket, then use instance profiles to make the credentials available to the instances

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_switch-role-ec2_instance-profiles.html

Comment: any good tutorials out there that you know of?  This stuff is really over my head

Comment: The AWS docs are pretty thorough, and the client libraries have built in support for getting credentials from the instance profile